Solving Systems of Linear PDE's in R3 w/ Singular Matrix Coefficients
been curious whether first-order linear systems of PDE's of the form $A\vec{u}_{x}+B\vec{u}_{y}+C\vec{u}_{z}=\vec{0}$ can be solved in the case where all matrices "A, B and C" are singular, my curiosity originated from me trying to come up with some conservative vector fields such that $\nabla \times \mathbf{\vec{F}}=\vec{0}$ for the purpose of creating some problems involving contour integrals. Now I know the system of PDE's generated
$$\begin{pmatrix}0&0&0\\ 0&0&-1\\ 0&1&0\end{pmatrix}\vec{u}_x+\begin{pmatrix}0&0&1\\ 0&0&0\\ -1&0&0\end{pmatrix}\vec{u}_y+\begin{pmatrix}0&-1&0\\ 1&0&0\\ 0&0&0\end{pmatrix}\vec{u}_z=\vec{0},\vec{u}=\begin{pmatrix}u^{(1)}\\u^{(2)}\\u^{(3)}\end{pmatrix}$$
can be partially "solved" by setting one of the component functions to zero, however I was just curious if there was more that could be done. I've done some research but don't seem to be finding much beyond potentially doing a singular value decomposition for each matrix and performing three different co-ordinate changes which doesn't seem too promising
any help would be appreciated!
